# NullPointerException com.liferay.portal.spring.util.SpringFactoryImpl.setBeanDefinitions

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, liferay

I'm using springFramework and I try to setBeanDefinitions, the problem is that this methode need a Map beanDefinition as a param... could U tell me plz how I could instantiate this param?

```
NullPointerException    at com.liferay.portal.spring.util.SpringFactoryImpl.setBeanDefinitions(SpringFactoryImpl.java:56)
```

additional information:
I try to deploy a liferay project without using liferay configuration files (only springFramework libraries), I created my own sessionFactory, my own dataSource ... etc!!
when I run the program, I'm able to create dataBase Schema basing on portlet-hbm.xml information... well now I try to instantiate beans for portal-spring.xml.. (which are xxxxpersistance.java)! those latters told me that they use  'com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.SessionFactory' as a required type and it can not convert property value of type 'org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl'!! so I tried to use the liferay libraries only for those beans and I try to instanciate them manually... but I wasn't able to setBeanDefinitions cause I need a Map beanDefinition as a param... I don't know if there is a way to get them using sessionFactory or not!! 
Thanks again

Comment: I would recommend reading the [Spring reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) and try some of the samples.

Comment: Without knowing what you're actually doing and in which context you need this, there's no way to answer this question. You'll need to give *a lot* more context if you really expect an answer

Answer (score 0):

You only mention junit in the tags to your question. I'd recommend to write unit tests without relying on the whole Liferay infrastructure. That will tremendously lower your required setup efforts and simplify your life a lot.